# Unknown element in JQUery click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a Html generated using JQUery and its like

```
<p class="fieldChoices title" style="">
  Choices:
  <input id="Choice1" value="option1" maxlength="150"/>
  <div class="seperator"/>
  <p class="deleteChoice1 cutsom_button deleteField"></p>
  <div class="seperator"/>
  <input id="Choice2" value="option2" maxlength="150"/>
  <div class="seperator"/>
  <p class="deleteChoice2 cutsom_button deleteField"></p>
  <div class="seperator"/>
</p>
```

I  am trying with on click of deleteChoice1 the corresponding Choice1 must be removed from the .fieldChoices using JQuery..

Also i may not know in JQuery whether i am clicking deleteChoice1 /deleteChoice2 ,,
so i dont know how to resolve it using JQuery..please suggest me....

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".deleteField").click(function(){
  $(this).prevAll("input:first").remove();
  $(this).prevAll(".seperator").remove();
  $(this).remove();
});
```

Though it'd be easier if you put each choice in a div.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following instead:

```
<p class="fieldChoices title" style="">
  Choices:
  <fieldset>
    <input id="Choice1" value="option1" maxlength="150"/>
    <div class="seperator"/>
    <span class="cutsom_button deleteField"></span>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="Choice2" value="option2" maxlength="150"/>
    <div class="seperator"/>
    <span class="cutsom_button deleteField"></span>
  </fieldset>
</p>

$("deleteField").bind("click", function(){
  $(this).parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: Oh good call. Otherwise the outer element remains. Gotta edit mine!

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<fieldset class="fieldChoices title">
  <legend>Choices</legend>
  <ul>
  <li>
      <input id="Choice1" value="option1" maxlength="150"/>
      <span class="deleteChoice cutsom_button deleteField"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
      <input id="Choice2" value="option2" maxlength="150"/>
      <span class="deleteChoice cutsom_button deleteField"></span>
  </li>
  </ul>
</fieldset>
```

jquery:

```
$(".fieldChoices li").each(function() {
         var choice = $(this);
       $(".deleteChoice", this).click(function() {
           choice.remove();
        });
      });
```